# Cancelled requests take a lot of time for a last new request in queue

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

I've tried a lot of approaches and still can't figure out how to resolve this issue.

I make url request with different parameters and show spinner (async request). But often I need to cancel a previous request and create a new one. Sometimes there are about 20 cancelled requests and the only one is active which is the last.

The last my example I've implemented with `AFNetworking`:

```
if ConnectionManager.sharedInstance.businessOperation != nil {
    ConnectionManager.sharedInstance.businessOperation!.cancel()
}

let manager = ConnectionManager.sharedInstance.businessManager
manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer(writingOptions: .allZeros)

var path = ConnectionManager.sharedInstance.path + ObjectPathComponent.Businesses.rawValue
path = path.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

NSLog("start loading")

ConnectionManager.sharedInstance.businessOperation = manager.GET(path,
    parameters: params,
    success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void in
        NSLog("loaded")

        ConnectionManager.sharedInstance.businessOperation = nil

        completionHandler(responseObject)
    },
    failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error.code != NSURLErrorCancelled {
            NSLog("business request error")
            completionHandler(error)
        }
        else {
            NSLog("cancelled")
        }
})
```

That's logs:

```
2015-07-09 00:48:49.639 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:48:50.060 [97349:3984504] loaded
2015-07-09 00:48:52.401 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:48:52.820 [97349:3984505] loaded
2015-07-09 00:49:58.622 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:03.364 [97349:3985559] loaded
2015-07-09 00:50:05.025 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:05.534 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:05.535 [97349:3985555] cancelled
2015-07-09 00:50:06.068 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:06.069 [97349:3985555] cancelled
2015-07-09 00:50:06.546 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:06.546 [97349:3985822] cancelled
2015-07-09 00:50:07.070 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:07.070 [97349:3985558] cancelled
2015-07-09 00:50:09.366 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:09.366 [97349:3985555] cancelled
2015-07-09 00:50:09.875 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:09.876 [97349:3985559] cancelled
2015-07-09 00:50:10.407 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:10.408 [97349:3985822] cancelled
2015-07-09 00:50:10.874 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:10.875 [97349:3985822] cancelled
2015-07-09 00:50:11.344 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:11.344 [97349:3985822] cancelled
2015-07-09 00:50:11.793 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:11.793 [97349:3985559] cancelled
2015-07-09 00:50:12.297 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:12.297 [97349:3985822] cancelled
2015-07-09 00:50:12.800 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:12.800 [97349:3985822] cancelled
2015-07-09 00:50:13.315 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:13.315 [97349:3984505] cancelled
2015-07-09 00:50:14.047 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:14.048 [97349:3984505] cancelled
2015-07-09 00:50:14.603 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:14.604 [97349:3984505] cancelled
2015-07-09 00:50:15.067 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:15.067 [97349:3984505] cancelled
2015-07-09 00:50:15.601 [97349:3984410] start loading
2015-07-09 00:50:15.601 [97349:3985559] cancelled
2015-07-09 00:50:50.896 [97349:3986273] loaded
```

If take a look at first, there will be 5 sec max delay between 'start loading' and 'loaded'. But when a lot of requests are cancelled, it can be more than 30 sec and this depends on how many requests are made.

Is there a way to change priority for the last request? I need to complete the request as fastest as I can but this queue, as I think, does not allow me to do this.

Will glad to hear any ideas.

Comment: Not sure exactly, but some questions: (1) Why are you creating new response and request serializers for each operation? (2) What's the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` for your `ConnectionManager` instance's operation queue?

Comment: It might be reading through [the implementation of `cancel`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/cf78b03e9fea1dcdb1222ad491c0d94bea185e89/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.m#L486). It's worth understanding, at least, that cancellation isn't immediate.

Comment: Well, I've changed `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to any but it does not help me anyway. The code was just pasted as example, that's not final. Just my scratches, so I could be mistaken with serializers

Comment: cancel for operations does not relate only for AFNetworking. It's for any Apple connection, as I know. I'm looking for a solution in order to avoid of such big delay.

Comment: I think you need to determine the specific cause of the delay.